# Is it bad practice to operate on a structure and assign the result to the same structure? Why?

Tags: c++, c, performance, kernel, structure

I don't recall seeing examples of code like this hypothetical snippet:

```
cpu->dev.bus->uevent = (cpu->dev.bus->uevent) >> 16; //or the equivalent using a macro
```

in which a member in a large structure gets dereferenced using pointers, operated on, and the result assigned back to the same field of the structure.

The kernel seems to be a place where such large structures are frequent but I haven't seen examples of it and became interested as to the reason why.

Is there a performance reason for this, maybe related to the time required to follow the pointers? Is it simply not good style and if so, what is the preferred way?

Comment: IMO, it is ok to use this kind of statement. Hint: Think of `i++` or `i+=5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's mush more a matter of history: the kernel is mostly written in C (not C++), and -in the original development intention- (K&R era) was thought as a "high level assembler", whose statement and expression should have a literal correspondence in C and ASM.  In this environment, `++i` `i+=1` and `i=i+1` are completely different things that translates in completely different CPU instructions

Compiler optimizations, at that time, where not so advanced and popular, so the idea to follow the pointer chain twice was often avoided by first store the resulting destination address in a local temporary variable (most likely a `register`) and than do the assignment.

(like `int* p = &a->b->c->d; *p = a + *p;`)

or trying to use compond instruction like `a->b->c >>= 16;`)

With nowadays computers (multicore processor, multilevel caches and piping) the execution of cone inside registers can be ten times faster respect to the memory access, following three pointers is faster than storing an address in memory, thus reverting the priority of the "business model".

Compiler optimization, then, can freely change the produced code to adequate it to size or speed depending on what is retained more important and depending on what kind of processor you are working with.

So -nowadays- it doesn't really matter if you write `++i` or `i+=1` or `i=i+1`: The compiler will most likely produce the same code, attempting to access `i` only once. and following the pointer chain twice will most likely be rewritten as equivalent to `(cpu->dev.bus->uevent) >>= 16` since `>>=` correspond to a single machine instruction in the x86 derivative processors.

That said (*"it doesn't really matter*"), it is also true that code style tend to reflect stiles and fashions of the age it was first written (since further developers tend to maintain consistency).

You code is not "bad" by itself, it just looks "odd" in the place it is usually written.

---

Just to give you an idea of what piping and prediction is. consider the comparison of two vectors:

```
bool equal(size_t n, int* a, int *b)
{
    for(size_t i=0; i<n; ++i)
       if(a[i]!=b[i]) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Here, as soon we find something different we sortcut saying they are different.

Now consider this:

```
bool equal(size_t n, int* a, int *b)
{
    register size_t c=0;
    for(register size_t i=0; i<n; ++i) 
       c+=(a[i]==b[i]);
    return c==n;
}
```

There is no shortcut, and even if we find a difference continue to loop and count.
But having removed the `if` from inside the loop, if `n` isn't that big (let's say less that 20) this can be 4 or 5 times faster!

An optimized compiler can even recognize this situation - proven there are no different side effects- can rework the first code in the second!

Answer (score 6):

There's nothing wrong with the statement syntactically, but it's easier to code it like this:

```
cpu->dev.bus->uevent >>= 16;
```

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing wrong with something like that, it appears as innocuous as:

```
i = i + 42;
```

If you're accessing the data items a *lot,* you could consider something like:

```
tSomething *cdb = cpu->dev.bus;
cdb->uevent = cdb->uevent >> 16;
// and many more accesses to cdb here
```

but, even then, I'd tend to leave it to the optimiser, which tends to do a better job than most humans anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing inherently wrong by doing

```
cpu->dev.bus->uevent = (cpu->dev.bus->uevent) >> 16;
```

but depending on the type of `uevent`, you need to be careful when shifting right like that, so you don't accidentally shift in unexpected bits into your value. For instance, if it's a 64-bit value

```
uint64_t uevent = 0xDEADBEEF00000000;
uevent = uevent >> 16; // now uevent is 0x0000DEADBEEF0000;
```

if you *thought* you shifted a 32-bit value and then pass the new `uevent` to a function taking a 64-bit value, you're not passing 0xBEEF0000, as you might have expected. Since the sizes fit (64-bit value passed as 64-bit parameter), you won't get any compiler warnings here (which you would have if you passed a 64-bit value as a 32-bit parameter).

Also interesting to note is that the above operation, while similar to

```
i = ++i;
```

which is undefined behavior (see http://josephmansfield.uk/articles/c++-sequenced-before-graphs.html for details), is still well defined, since there are no side effects in the right-hand side expression.